# I need to do an background threads with loop to infinity time about this code

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, schedule

I need to do an background threads with loop to infinity time about this code.
if it's possible I need to have an sleep about 15 seconds.

the code is:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "my url string")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "my post string"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: You need to check out DispatchQueues. https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9

Comment: There's no need to shout (all cap title) and don't use old Foundation types in Swift when they have a native Swift alternative (such as `URLRequest`, `URL` and `String`).

Comment: You cannot run anything every 15 seconds when an app is in the background on iOS.  You can enable the Background fetch option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project, but that will only get you periodic  background time.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56

Answer (score 0):

As David S says in his comment, you can't run tasks indefinitely in the background in iOS. You can ask for background time, and then you get about 3 minutes.

URLSession has OS level support for background downloading of files, but it won't do a `POST`, and it won't poll the server that frequently for a `GET`. In short I think you're out of luck on iOS.

(Apple goes to great length to keep apps from running constantly in order to preserve battery life. Most of the time the user's phone is locked and the CPU goes to a very low power mode.)